# How autoplot (ggplot) gets scores and loadings from prcomp

Tags: r, ggplot2, prcomp, autoplot

I know that there are lots of discussions out there that treat this subject matter... but every time I encounter this, I never find a consistent, satisfying answer.

I'm trying to create a very basic graphical depiction of a principal components analysis model. I always aim to *not* use packages that automatically generate plots for me because I want the control.

Every time I try to make a PCA plot with loadings, I am stumped by how the canned functions relate their site-specific scores with the model's loading vectors. This is despite the myriad nodes out there treating this matter, most of which just use the canned functions without explaining how the numbers got from a basic PCA model to the biplot (they just use the canned function).

For the example code below, I'll use autoplot. If I make a PCA model and use autoplot, I get a very cool graph. But I want to know *how* they get these numbers- the scores get rescaled, and I have no idea how the vectors are relativized the way they are on the plot. Can anyone walk me through how I would get these numbers relativized data in dataframes of my own (both scores and vectors) so I can make the aesthetic changes I want without using autoplot??

```
d <- iris

m1 <- prcomp(d[,1:4], scale=T)

scores <- data.frame(m1$x[,1:2])

library(ggplot2)

#Scores range from about -2.5 to +3
ggplot(scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point()

#Scores range from about -0.15 to 0.22, no clue where the relativized loadings come from
autoplot(m1, loadings = T)
```

Comment: Could you provide d?

Comment: Sorry... not sure why that wasn't showing before. Looks to be there now.

Comment: You know that you use `ggfortify`? See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056144/r-ggfortify-objects-of-type-prcomp-not-supported-by-autoplot>. In the second answer `ggfortify` with `autoplot` is compared to the direct way with `ggplot2` (with example)! You can also use `summary(your_autoplot)` to get some information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to walk you through and simplify the steps that `autoplot` uses to draw a PCA plot, so you can do this yourself quite easily in ggplot.

`autoplot` is actually an S3 generic function, so it's more accurate to talk about the method `ggfortify:::autoplot.prcomp` uses, since this is the function that is dispatched when you call `autoplot` on a `prcomp` object.

Let's start with your own example:

```r
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)

d <- iris

m1 <- prcomp(d[, 1:4], scale = TRUE)

scores <- data.frame(m1$x[, 1:2])
```

The scores are normalized by dividing each column by its own root mean squared error

```r
scores[] <- lapply(scores, function(x) x / sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)))
```

The loadings are simply obtained from the `rotation` member of the `prcomp` object:

```r
loadings <- as.data.frame(m1$rotation)[1:2]
```

There is some internal scaling to ensure that the loadings appear on the same scale as the adjusted PC scores, but as far as I can tell this is simply for visual effect. The scaling amounts to about 0.2 here, and is calculated as follows:

```r
scale <- min(max(abs(scores$PC1))/max(abs(loadings$PC1)),
             max(abs(scores$PC2))/max(abs(loadings$PC2))) * 0.8

scale
#> [1] 0.1987812
```

We now have enough to recreate the autoplot using vanilla ggplot code.

```r
ggplot(scores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = loadings * scale,
               aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2),
               color = "red", arrow = arrow(angle = 25, length = unit(4, "mm")))
```

[image]

Aside from the axis titles, this is identical to the autoplot:

```r
autoplot(m1, loadings = TRUE)
```

[image]